# Spring MVC: BindingResult allegedly declared without preceding model attribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am experiencing a very peculiar behavior with Spring MVC 3.1.0.M2 that suddenly popped out:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin/participants/{participantId}")
public class ParticipantEditController extends ParticipantControllerSupport {
    @ModelAttribute("participant")
    public Participant getParticipant(
        @PathVariable("participantId") final long participantId) {
        // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{tab}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ModelAndView save(
        @ModelAttribute("participant") final Participant participant,
        final BindingResult errors) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I'm submitting my form I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors/BindingResult argument declared without preceding model attribute. Check your handler method signature!
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.support.ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:65)
    ...
```

What's troubling me is that my `BindingResult` *does* immediately follow the model attribute in the method signature.

I've tried it with and without a `@Valid` annotation and with more or less other parameters, to no avail.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may be a bug in the ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver (or a releated class).  Consider reporting it to the spring team.  3.1.0.M2 is still a development release; it may be a good idea to get 3.0.6 (the latest ga release) and see if you can reproduce the error.

Comment: I have submitted this topic to the Spring community forums: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115054-MVC-3.1.0.M2-BindingResult-allegedly-declared-without-preceding-model-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem. The culprit was another method in a parent class that used a ' `@ModelAttribute` to calculate another model attribute:

```
@ModelAttribute("foobar")
public String getFoobar(@ModelAttribute("participant") Participant participant) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is not the correct answer.  Try not declaring your parameters as final.  *ex.*

```
public ModelAndView save(
    @ModelAttribute("participant") Participant participant,
    BindingResult errors)
```

Comment: I can happily confirm that this is not the correct answer. :-)